# Link to another folder when a certain folder is called using an env variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symlink

I've got this code architecture :

- root

  - locales
  - subdomain1

    - locales
  - subdomain2

    - locales
  - .env

In my .env, I've got an env file called "DOMAIN=XXX". If that variable is not set, /root/locales is used. If it's set `DOMAIN=subdomain1`, I want the locales file of the subdomain to be used `/root/subdomain1/locales`.

Knowing that in my env I got `DOMAIN=subdomain1`, I want PHP to change that path to `/root/subdomain1/locales/XXX`.

Example :

```
// In index.php I got 
symlink('/root/locales/XXX', '/root/subdomain1/locales/XXX'); // I get the "subdomain1" from the .env variable

// In other files I've got
require_once('/root/locales/XXX')
```

I've tried using PHP's symlink function, but it doesn't do anything. Am I using that function properly? Does any of you have other ways of doing this? I can not change the path manually in every require/include cuz I've got thousands.

EDIT :
In other files I've got require_once('/root/locales/XXX') that I'm not able to change, that's why I want to create a symlink, to update the path for all the `require_once` that exists without having to edit each and every one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have both a file and a symlink with the same name in the same directory, so your call to `symlink()` can't work.

A solution would be to change your hierarchy to the following:

- root

  - main

    - locales
  - subdomain1

    - locales
  - subdomain2

    - locales
  - .env

When `DOMAIN` is not defined, create a symlink like this (beware of the parameter order of [`symlink()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php)):

```
symlink('/root/main/locales', '/root/locales');
```

When `DOMAIN` is defined, create a symlink like this:

```
symlink('/root/'.$_ENV['DOMAIN'].'/locales', '/root/locales');
```

You can handle both cases at once:

```
$domain = $_ENV['DOMAIN'] ?? 'main';
@unlink('/root/locales');
symlink("/root/$domain/locales", '/root/locales');
```

You will find a simple online test [here](https://3v4l.org/cGLS6#v8.3.1) which shows that symlinks actually work.

Of course, the PHP user will need permission to create a symlink in /root, so it may still fail.

But do you really need to create it on the fly? Can the .env file suddenly change? If not, then you should just
manually create the symlink on the command line.

Finally, another solution would be to fix your PHP scripts to include the correct file. You said
"I cannot change the path manually" because you have many, but nothing prevents you from writing a utility that
automatically scans and fixes your scripts. Basically you just need to replace the line:

```
require_once('/root/locales/XXX');
```

with another implementation, so it's a simple search and replace.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, this is not working tho. The symlink does nothing, and the require_once is not using the symlink, but it's using the path that's inside the initial require. And as I said, I can not mass change the path in require_once :(

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? Have you tried your code and can confirm that it's working for you?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy First, as I said, PHP must have permission to create the symlink. Second, you must delete /root/locales before calling `symlink()`. From what you said, I suspect you didn't.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy I added an `unlink()` in my answer so that it works if a link already exists. And, yes, I did a test and it works.

Comment: It might be a permission error then, I'll look into it :/ Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy I added [this online test](https://3v4l.org/cGLS6#v8.3.1) to show it works.